# How to fix view retain cycle causing subview's dealloc to not be called?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I have a view controller which instantiates a bunch of UIButton subclasses and adds them to its self.view and also to a mutable array. These subclasses in turn have a retain property which points to another view. In most cases, the view property points back to the UIButton subclass' superview (the view controller's self.view to which they were added). But not always and not necessarily, which is why I am using this property and not the inherited superview one.

The problem I'm having is that when the view controller's dealloc does:

```
- (void)dealloc
{
  [UIBUttonSubClassesArray release];
  [super dealloc];
}
```

the UIButton subclasses' dealloc is not being called. So the additional release for the view property in these subclasses doesn't get called and, even when the view controller is dealloced, I'm leaking the view controller's view once for each of these UIButton subclasses.

But, if instead I make the subclasses' view property an assign, so that I need not call release in their dealloc, their dealloc does get called and even when there's no code referencing the view now, the app crashes.

Any ideas?

Comment: Obviously no arc, so are you releasing the buttons at all, or just the array?

Comment: What views other than their superview do your buttons reference?

Comment: @CodaFi no ARC right. And the buttons should be released when I call release on the array (the array should call release on them). I also tried calling removeAllObjects before releasing the array

Comment: @VadimYelagin at this point only their superviews really. Which is why I ended up dropping the whole view property approach and using the superview inherited one. But thing is, these buttons are conceptually sprites whose CALayers are animated and, potentially, also have a trigger on them (which is why they are UIButton subclasses). And then view property allows for the triggers to animate different layers in specific ways too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your viewcontroller is not in the retain cycle, you can break the cycle in its dealloc (and in its viewDidUnload too) by setting your extra retain properties in your buttons to nil.

Although it is always preferable not to create retain cycles in the first place, I don't see enough clue in your question on how they should be avoided in your case.

Comment: Yeah the view controller itself is not retained. its view is. And like I said, I was only doing this cause potentially a different view other than the controller's main view could be referenced by the buttons. But setting the property to nil apparently crashes the app too... weird. In any case, at this point I got rid of the property and I'm using the inherited superview one for the case where the view property would point to the controller's view